# Navigate between JSP Page change context root

Tags: java, jsp, navigation

I'm currently working on an old Java Web application (running only on IE5).
In this application, there is a menu and the pages are called in different ways:

```
self.navigate ( 'cretIhmMenu.do?cret=rejete');
```

and

```
self.navigate ( 'jsp / CRET / CretIdCreationInteractIhm.jsp')
```

In those called directly on the jsp (2nd example), the redirection works correctly however, the ContextRoot of my application has changed and no image is displayed later ...

How to navigate between pages without changing the ContextRoot (keep the one from the root of the web app)

cordially

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try JSTL core tag `c:set`

```
<c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

Comment: I can't use jstl... but i don't understand why the actual app work on the server, but mine fail when trying to navigate locally..